# Laravel Cashier Create Subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

It's very easy to create a stripe customer, associate a card with that customer and charge them at anytime after. However, using Laravel cashier it's not so easy to subscribe a user to a plan at any time after.

```
Auth::user()->subscription(Input::get($new_plan_id))->create($card_token, array(
    'email' => Auth::user()->email
));
```

The card tokens are generated when the user adds a card in my settings. I have tried storing the token at this point and using it when a user wants to update their subscription but I get the error:

`You cannot use a Stripe token more than once`

Comment: With that, you're creating a new Customer. You should change the subscription of the existing customer.

Answer (score 1):

Below code is work for me in Laravel 5.1 :

For Create Subscription :

```
$creditcardToken = Input::get( 'stripeToken' );
$user->subscription(Input::get( 'subscription' ))->create($creditcardToken,['email' => $user->email,'description' => 'Customer from DevLaravel']);
```

For Update Subscription you have to follow some steps:

```
1. // Get Subscription
$subscription = $user->subscriptions()->where('stripe_id', 'sub_5vp6DX7N6yVJqY')->first();
2. // Update the subscription plan
$subscription->setStripePlan('new-plan-name');
3. // Apply the coupon
$subscription->applyCoupon($coupon);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply call it normally, without the cc token:

```
$user->newSubscription('main', $plan)->create();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this was possible in 2016, but it definitely isn't now :(

Answer (score 0):

You can pass customer as 3rd parameter to `create` method.

```
$customer = $user->stripe_id ?
    \Laravel\Cashier\Customer::retrieve($user->stripe_id) : 
    null;

$user->subscription($plan)->create($token, $meta, $customer);
```

Comment: And how do we get `$plan`?